# How to see if a file was ever included in the project file?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to quickly see whether a file, which is currently part of source control but not included in the project, has ever been included in the project?

The only thing I know to do is manually review previous versions of the project file one by one which would be unreasonably cumbersome.

Any better way to accomplish this?

EDIT: Just to be clear, I am not looking for history on the target file itself. I am wanting to see if the project file (the .csproj file) ever had a reference to the filename.

So for clarity in your examples, let's say the project name is myproject.csproj and the target file is myfile.txt.

Comment: What do you mean by "included in the project"? Is there a file that contains a list of file names for the files include in the project?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, the .csproj file contains references to all files included in the project.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not that hard:

```
git log --pretty=%h | while read revision; do
    lines=$( git ls-tree -r $revision | grep the-file-I-want | wc -l )
    if [ $lines -gt 0 ]; then
        echo $revision has the file
    fi
done
```

which can be written in a 1-liner, just in case.

Comment: and I bet the filename can be also specified in the git `ls-tree` call, but alas. Grep could provide more flexibility

Comment: Could you do this more simply with the pick axe?

Comment: @eftshift0 Would you mind looking at my edit and then confirming this is still correct?

Comment: Oh, this is not correct. You actually want to be able to check the project metadata (say, IDE's metadata?). IDE's metadata is normally not included in version control and, if you did use git to track it, you would need to know how to read the file. Therefore, I will delete the answer I provided in a few minutes.

Comment: Is there a way to see if the file is included in the current working tree with a command? If there is, I might adjust the script accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple working solution (for me) maybe the following:

1. Change dir to the root of the repository.
2. Suppose the file your are searching for was in subfolder (omit `**/` to search only into the root folder).
3. Issue the command `git log --all --full-history --oneline -- **/{{FILE_TO_SEARCH_FOR}}`.

So you will get the commits where, regardless of the subfolder, the file **{{FILE_TO_SEARCH_FOR}}** has been found.

---

### **Edit**

Search if a file has been ever referenced inside a CSPROJ file:

`git log --all --full-history --oneline -S {{FILE_TO_SEARCH_FOR}} -- **/*.csproj`

Comment: So is FILE_TO_SEARCH_FOR a string that git is searching file contents for? Or is it just searching actual files? Because, just to be clear, I'm not looking for information on the actual file itself. I'm wanting to know if it's ever referenced in the .csproj file.

Comment: I understood, I edit my post adding what you need... I  hope! :)